# Google Cloud Datastore "out of bounds of 'Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER'"

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

One of the data in datastore is 7766277975020011920 and similarities.

[image]

The error shown in nodejs is -

```
Error: We attempted to return all of the numeric values, but chain value 7766277975129421920 is out of bounds of 'Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER'.
```

It suggested "options.wrapNumbers=true" to the file

```
"node_modules/@google-cloud/datastore/build/src/entity.js:412:19".
```

But I am using google cloud RUN version and not able to edit the files. How can I pass it ?

Comment: Can you share the queries you are running in your application? The `wrapNumbers` option can be passed as an option when querying or getting entities from Datastore according to the [client reference](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/datastore/latest/datastore/datastorerequest#_google_cloud_datastore_DatastoreRequest_runQuery_member_1_)

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for providing docs reference. Your method works and it is showing "DatastoreInt" for number results. Please can you create an answer of it ?
``` const [values] = await datastore.runQuery(query,{"wrapNumbers":true});         ```

Comment: @LeornarAung I posted an answer from my comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving my comment into an answer, according to the Node.js client reference for Datastore, when you run queries or calls for entities, you [can pass options as an additional argument](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/datastore/latest/datastore/datastorerequest#_google_cloud_datastore_DatastoreRequest_runQuery_member_1_), which supports passing the `wrapNumbers = True` option:

```js
const [values] = await datastore.runQuery(query,{"wrapNumbers":true});
```

You can use that in your calls to avoid receiving `out of bounds` errors for large integers. The rest of the supported options are documented in [this code snippet](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-datastore/blob/main/src/request.ts#L439-L451) from the official repository:

```js
const options = {
    consistency: 'string',
    gaxOptions: {},
    wrapNumbers: true,
};
```